# How to do timestamp to DateTime conversion in laravel 5

Tags: datetime, laravel-5, date-conversion

How can i change the timestamp format into dateTime format in laravel 5, while fetching the timestamp from the table.?

```
<td>{{ $nam->date("Y-m-d H:i:s", lastLoginTime) }}</td>
```

When I tried this one, its showing error "`Call to undefined method stdClass::date()`".
Anyone help me to solve it.

Comment: I think it's not correct code. $nam->date . -> not call to php functions. Also date correct its `date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )` and lastLoginTime it's not a var.

Comment: am new in laravel. Can you explain it little more. Here is my blade page.

Comment: It's not oonly a question of Laravel. It's a question of php. Edit your assk and putting more corde if you like help. With code on question, my comment say: `$name->date` it's not correct. Also `date("Y-m-d H:i:s", lastLoginTime) ` it's not correct.

Comment: Formatted post, added tag, removed thanks

Comment: i got the correct code.  {{ date('Y/m/d H:i:s',($nam->lastLoginTime)) }}   now am getting in the proper format. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the Model you can add the below function to add dates to diffForHumans() function:

```
funtion getDates()
{
    return array('created_at', 'updated_at', 'lastLoginTime');
}
```

etc etc.

Or you can use the following:

```
{{ $nam->lastLoginTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}
```

Comment: function should be like `public funtion getDates(){ // codes }`